# How does Django 1.4 CSRF work?

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I have that ***urls.py***:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        r'^login/$', 
        'django.contrib.auth.views.login', 
        {'template_name': 'loyalty/login.html'}, 
        name='login'
    ),
    url(
        r'^logout/$', 
        'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', 
        {'next_page': '/', },
        name='logout'),
)
```

and have template **login.html***:

```
{% extends "loyalty/auth.html" %}
  {% load i18n %}  

  {% block auth_form %}
  {% if messages %}
  <ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}

  <form action="" method="post" id="login-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.username.errors %}{{ form.username.errors }}{% endif %}
    {{ form.username }}
    {% if form.password.errors %}{{ form.password.errors }}{% endif %}
    {{ form.password }}
    <input type="hidden" name="this_is_the_login_form" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">{% trans 'Log in' %}</button>
  </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

and i have in ***settings.py***:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

But this gives me this error:

> Forbidden (403)
>   CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>   Help
>   Reason given for failure:
>   CSRF cookie not set.

In administrative interface, I have same problem.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Problem in browser. Tried an other browser and all works fine. Didn't understand why I had this problem, because I tried clean cache and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You probably aren't passing the Request context from your view.

Example:

```
def show_form(request):
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = MyForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():

    return render_to_response("template_to_display.html", {'form':form}, context_instance = template.RequestContext(request))
```

Update: I would suggest rearranging your middleware. Try removing the localemiddleware or placing it at last. The django default is [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES)

Comment: I use the standard Django application, it sees in urls.py: django.contrib.auth
In administrative interface I have same problem.

Comment: @lmasikl: Updated the answer take a look